# Is it possible to mix and match armor sets?

Tags: mass-effect-3

I just bought the Cerberus Armor set for a hefty price and sadly it takes a few of my stats down to zero. Is it possibly to split up the armor set components so that I can keep the Cerberus health boost and the Kassa Fabrication shield regeneration?

Comment: There is actually an achievement/trophy for this:
Always Prepared-Obtain two non-customizable suits of armor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, in the armor selection screen you can toggle between several different sets for each piece of armor you wish to equip.  Once you've selected the basic armor set at the top of the menu, you can move down and choose individual armor bits from different sets if you so desire.

For instance, I've got the Kingdoms of Amalur "cross-promotional-marketing-synergy" set, and I'm only wearing the helmet from it, as the standard N7 set gives a pretty substantial health boost which I, sadly, tend to need often.

**However,** after spending some time investigating and testing, we've determined that there are some special "full set" armor types that cannot be broken up.

The sets that can't be mixed and matched are:

- Cerberus Armor
- Terminus Armor
- Inferno Armor
- Blood Dragon Armor
- Collector Armor

The sets you *can* mix and match are:

- N7
- Hahne-Kedar
- Armax Arsenal
- Serrice Council
- Kassa Fabrication
- Ariake Technologies
- Rosenkov Materials

Comment: If I select the Cerberus armor set I cannot change any of its components and if I select the first armor set I cannot see any Cerberus components in it.

Comment: @row1 That's interesting.  I don't have that particular set yet, perhaps there's something unique about it?  I've got 3 sets so far, and I can mix and match to my heart's content.

Comment: this is my first armor set so now I feel like an idiot. If we can confirm that some armor sets can't be broken up then I will accept your answer. Thanks.

Comment: @row1, have you tried moving *left* instead of *right* to select other armor pieces on the armor menu?  I think it's possible that when you select one of the other sets the rest of the sliders change position for you, which might be tripping you up.

Comment: OK I just bought the collector armor set and I cannot modify that either. So I guess there are special sets that you can't breakup-the collector set would look very strange being mixed.

Comment: yeah going left or right they are definitely not there (only have two items in some categories)

Comment: @row1, fascinating!  I've added this info to my answer.  I'll try to find out if there's a list of the ones that you can't replace items in.